# How do I find child components without having to specify the HOC wrapping them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, enzyme

Often when I'm working with Material-ui its extensible nature gets in the way of testing.

This is because even though I am using, say:

```js
const MyEventButton = () => (<IconButton />
  <Event />
</IconButton>)
```

What I get in the test output of a shallow render is:

```html
<WithStyles(ForwardRef(IconButton)) >
  <Event />
</WithStyles(ForwardRef(IconButton)) >
```

This HOC wrapping is not something I overly care about for my tests (i.e. I'm *not* testing that the component is `WithStyles` or uses `ForwardRef`), because it's an implementation detail which could change without me wanting/needing to update tests.

Ultimately, this means I cannot write my tests as:

```js
it('Renders IconButton', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyEventButton />);
  expect(wrapper.exists('IconButton')).toEqual(true);
}
```

I have to do:

```js
it('Renders IconButton', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyEventButton />);
  expect(wrapper.exists('WithStyles(ForwardRef(IconButton))')).toEqual(true);
}
```

Which feels like I've coupled my tests too tightly with materials current inner workings.

Is there a way of the tests peering inside the HOC and getting the base Child component? Preferably without having to `dive` or guess where in the component it is with `children().at(0)` an poking around. Using `wrapper.exists() also fails for similar reasons.

I have had a look around Stackoverflow and the internet and not found a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You don't have to create the component to test it exists

Instead of doing:

```
expect(wrapper.exists('WithStyles(ForwardRef(IconButton))')).toEqual(true);
```

or the component

```
expect(wrapper.exists(<IconButton/>)).toEqual(true);
```

Just tell enzyme you expect the component's *function* to exist, and it will understand:

```
expect(wrapper.exists(IconButton)).toEqual(true); // passes
```